# How to fix broken unit testing after upgrading Typesafe Stack?

Tags: eclipse, scala, noclassdeffounderror, scala-2.10, scalatest

I just upgraded to Typesafe IDE for Scala 2.10.1 (I had been using 2.9.something). Scala works, but unit testing with `org.scalatest` no longer works. I get

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest
```

(This is on Mac OS X 10.7.5.) How do I fix this?

In an existing project I have scalatest_2.9.2 in the folder org.scalatest, and scalatest_2.9.2-1.8.jar in Referenced Libraries. There are no compilation issues. What do I need to install or move?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

ClassManifest was deprecated in 2.10 so it is binary just incompability issue (major scala versions are **NOT** guaranteed to be binary compatible) of scalatest that was compiled against 2.9.2 (as you can see from the artifact name). The solution is pretty simple: just swap `scalatest_2.9.2-1.8.jar` with [recent scalatest version](http://www.scalatest.org/download) compiled for 2.10, e.g. with "scalatest_2.10-1.9.1"